# Tcl package textutil disappeared

Tags: tcl

After my last Ubuntu update (apparently), the Tcl package `textutil` does not exist any longer, so `package require textutil` fails. In the man-page it says *"The bundle is deprecated, and it will be removed in a future release of Tcllib, after the next release. It is recommended to use the relevant sub packages instead for whatever functionality is needed by the using package or application."*

I can't figure out how to use the sub-packages. I need the procs `textutil::adjust`, `textutil::tabify::untabify` and `textutil::undent`.

Could someone be so kind and let me know what I should now put behind `package require`? Or do I need to install new Ubuntu packages beforehand? Thanks a lot!

---

Sorry, the problem seems to be a different one. I recently put `$HOME/anaconda3/bin` (related to Python) into `PATH` in `.tcshrc` (the `tcsh` config file), and just doing this screws up the `tcl_pkgPath` (only points to `$HOME/acaconda3/lib`). What the ... I'll post a question on this separately.

Still, the question remains when `textutil` should really disappear at some later point.

Comment: Looking at the list of textutil packages and their docs, you need [`textutil::adjust`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/adjust.md) and [`textutil::tabify`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/tabify.md)

Comment: Here's the link to my other post on the interaction between anaconda3 and tcl: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78154535/3852630

Comment: @Shawn: Thanks a lot, that worked. The calls are `textutil::adjust::adjust`, `textutil::adjust::undent`, and `textutil::tabify::untabify2`, in case somebody needs this as well.