# anaconda search path ruins tcl package search path

Tags: tcl, anaconda3

I encountered the following problem. When I put `$HOME/anaconda3/bin` into the `path` variable in my `.tcshrc`, it somehow (even without starting anything from the anaconda3 directory) ruins the search path for Tcl packages (`tcl_pkgPath`). Instead of

```
% tclsh
% puts $tcl_pkgPath
/usr/local/lib/tcltk /usr/local/share/tcltk           /usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/tcltk /usr/share/tcltk         /usr/lib/tcltk/tcl8.6 /usr/lib
```

I get

```
% tclsh
% puts $tcl_pkgPath
{/home/moeller/anaconda3/lib}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how this can be avoided? How can these two totally unrelated software packages interfere?

Comment: tcl_pkgPath does not depend on the PATH environment variable. However, changing the PATH variable may cause a completely different binary to be picked up when running the `tclsh` command. That other `tclsh` may use a different tcl_pkgPath.

Comment: @SchelteBron: I see, thanks a lot! They apparently pack `tclsh` and `wish` into their distribution, presumably for `tkinter`? I wonder how I can work around this...

Comment: Work-around: After encountering this problem, I wasn't sure what other consequences would arise from including `acaconda3/bin` in the search path in `.bashrc` (or even other anaconda initialization). So I wrote a bash-script which just sets the path and starts `anaconda-navigator`.

Comment: Putting the location of the original `tclsh` before `anaconda3/bin` in the PATH variable should work for running a regular `tclsh`. I just don't know if that breaks anaconda. Your work-around seems like a good way to handle the situation.

Comment: I finally gave up on anaconda-navigator. I'm not sure whether it's related to my work-around, but somehow I lost all python packages like `numpy`. Reinstalling anaconda-navigator didn't help. Maybe a search path is not set properly in my solution. Just wanted to mention this.